# discount entity for ERD- onine shopping

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently making an ER diagram for my product model. But I'm confused that the **DISCOUNT** needs an entity to connect with the product module or it can just be an attributes of the product?
my current product module:
the

**PRODUCT**

PRODUCT_ID(PK)

PRODUCT_NAME

PRODUCT_PRICE

PRODUCT_TYPE

PRODUCT_COLOUR

PRODUCT_SIZE

STOCK_UNIT (FK)

---

this is the entity i try to make for DISCOUNT

PRODUCT_ID (PK,FK)

ADMIN_ID(FK)

DISCOUNT_DATE

DISCOUNTED_PRICE

In my scenario, some of the specific product prices can be discounted with value/ per centage. But I am confused that do i need to put the discount value/percentage as an attribute or an entity in the product module because there are only some products that have the discounted price.

I hope that my explanation is clear enough ><

Comment: will you have different discount ratios for different cases? Example %10 discount for new customers and %15 for students for same product.

Comment: I'd also expect that discounts have a duration. Such as 2022-05-22 09:00:00 to 2022-05-22 17:00:00

Comment: I expect that the discount ratio is determine by the admin which i stated at the discount entity (or it can be any number ) and i do expect that the discount will not have a durations because i just want to make it simple as the price won't change after the discount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on question and comments, I suggest:

```
Discount Table
--------------
DISCOUNT_ID (PrimaryKey)
PRODUCT_ID (ForeignKey)
IsPERCENT (Bool)
DISCOUNT (Float|Double)
FROM_DATE (DateTime)
TILL_DATE (DateTime)
```

`IsPercent` should be True if discount is to calculated using Percentage.

`Discount` should be value (treated as percent or Currency depending on IsPercent)

Also in your program, validate that `Discount` value doesn't go above 100 if `IsPercent` is TRUE

Comment: can i ask that will the discount id appear at product table? (i'm new in this sorry(TwT)) or the product the product id in the discount table wil  be enough?

Comment: You would want to learn about sql joins (check out W3school). You don't need Discount information in the Product table, but using joins you can get data from both tables that you can display/manipulate in your program.

Comment: i see, thanks for your anwer mr nazim. it helps me a lot